# Raising a point layer off the ground

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, 3d

I am working with a layer of potential sites for security cameras and I want to create a viewshed from each potential site. I have a point layer of XY data that shows the location of each camera, but no Z data. I want to raise each camera off the ground by 30 feet or so. What's the easiest way to go about doing this? I am working with ArcGIS Pro with an Advanced License with Spatial Analyst add-on.

So far I have tried the "Add Z Information" tool, but so far that has either only filled Z-titled field with null values, or given me an error telling me that "The input feature class must have Z values."

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What have you tried already?  You can [edit] your question to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your point data reference has the same Cartesian coordinate reference system as your surface model (this idea applies to all ArcGIS tools that use both raster and vector data).  Add an attribute to your points table callded OFFSETA and populate that with the camera height above ground.  Run your viewshed.

See [Using Viewshed and Observer Points for visibility analysis](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/using-viewshed-and-observer-points-for-visibility.htm) for more details.